# Very simple system of two first order ordinary differential equations. (3.1-2)

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I am not certain what to do here. Please assist by setting up the first two or three steps of this very simple system of first order ordinary differential equations. My differential equations textbook states to use the "elimination method" to crack this. We may also solve by the matrix method where the size of this matrix is $2$x$2$. And lastly the final answer uses $t$ as the independent variable which both $x$ and $y$ are dependent on. I believe the general solution should look something like this $y = c_1e^{\lambda_1 t}+c_2e^{\lambda_2 t}$.

$$x' = 2x + 2y$$
$$y' = 5x - y$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write as following
$$\frac{d}{dt}\pmatrix{x\\y}=\pmatrix{2&2\\5&-1}\pmatrix{x\\y}$$
find eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $$A=\pmatrix{2&2\\5&-1}$$
that is $\lambda_{1}=-3$ with $v_1=\pmatrix{1\\1}$ and $\lambda_{2}=4$ with $v_2=\pmatrix{-2\\5}$.

The solution is $$\pmatrix{x\\y}=c_1e^{\lambda_1t}v_1+c_2e^{\lambda_2t}v_2 $$

Comment: Thank you for the help. It was embarrassingly too easy. I should have known how to solve it.